# Why not 'choice of an opinion'

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Which of these sentence below makes sense?

- The choice of opinion is simple.
- The choice of an opinion is simple.

I think 'opinion' in this case is a countable noun. It should be accompanied by an article. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: It's not about the preposition. Read up on "zero article."Good Luck!

Comment: I read about zero article. We should not use articles if we want to mention things in general, and in this sense, nouns are uncountable or plural. What do you mean by that Kris?

Comment: Why can't *opinion* be used "in general"?

Comment: If 'opinion' is referred to as a 'general' sense, then it is 'the beliefs or views of a group of people'; it is not my views or my beliefs any more. Am I correct?

Comment: These are phrases not sentences. Please present a complete sentence so the context is clear.

Comment: I updated to make them full sentences.

Comment: Both are grammatical but their meanings are completely different.

Comment: Where the difference lies? Please help me clarify it.

Comment: That's not a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of  opinion  may differ  from person to person because**English is dificult**  may  be  an  opinion expressed by  a  nonnative  speaker  while   a  native speaker  may  have  a different  opinion.

we say the meaning of opinion   but   not  an  opinion.

In a generic sense we use  opinion without article. when  we are talking about  the opinion  of   a  particular person  we  say  an  opinion

Comment: I saw this sentence, and it made me confused as well. Here it is: 'I don’t like his choice of friends'. I just need some rules to get rid of the confusion that I've had.

Comment: It seems to me that after 'of' if nouns have both uncountable and countable forms, English people are more likely to use 'uncountable form' to add information for the preceding noun. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: opinion is both countable and uncountable.The choice of opinion is   used used in a general sense.An opinion of  a particularperson  is particular to him..It is the opinion of the Indians is that British English is the  correct. so  zero article, Indefinite article and the is  possible